# How to Detect Payment Completion Automatically in Wallet App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, payment-gateway, wallet

I'm developing a android wallet application using Jetpack Compose and Kotlin. One challenge I'm facing is how to automatically retrieve the payment status once the user has completed a transaction. I'm unsure of the approach to implement this feature seamlessly within my app. Any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm currently retrieving the transaction status every 10 seconds, but I feel it's not ideal as it could affect performance.

Comment: Generally you want to do push messaging rather than polling for status changes.  However we don't know enough about how your app works to really tell you if this is the right solution or not.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about push messaging? @GabeSechan

Comment: Push messaging is something like FCM, where the server sends a message to the client when there's something they need to know/for them to do, rather than them constantly polling and checking for changes

Comment: Thank you @GabeSechan, my issue has been resolved. I'm using webhooks and FCM, and now my application is running as I intended.